# How to integrate: $\int \frac{1+\sqrt{x+1}}{1-\sqrt{x+1}}dx$

Tags: integration, substitution

I want to integrate this fraction using t-substitution:
$\int \frac{1+\sqrt{x+1}}{1-\sqrt{x+1}}dx$
$x\gt-1, $t=\sqrt{x+1}$

My attempt: $dx = \frac{dt}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}} }$
$\int \frac{1+t}{1-t}dx$
$\int \frac{(1+t)\times 2 \sqrt{x+1 }}{1-t}dt$
$\int \frac{2 \sqrt{x+1 }+2t \sqrt{x+1 }}{1-t}dt$
$2 \int \frac{ \sqrt{x+1 }}{1-t}dt + 2 \int \frac{t\sqrt{x+1 }}{1-t} dt$

I'm not sure how to continue. I think the antiderivative of $\sqrt{x+1}$ is $\frac{2{(x+1)}^\frac 32}{3}$. But how do I handle the denominator?

Comment: Hint: since $x=t^2-1$, $dx=2tdt$.

Comment: Hence your integral equals $2\int\frac{t+t^2}{1-t}dt.$ Then, use partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think the comments answer it.

Comment: just replace your remaining $\sqrt{x+1}$ terms by $t$